# String as agrv[] from command line

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass a string ("ciao") as argument from command line. The code is below:

```
gcc contaparolefile.c -o parole.txt ciao
```

and the output:

```
gcc.exe: error: ciao: No such file or directory
```

Maybe I'm getting the syntax wrong

Comment: `gcc` is a compiler, not an interpreter. The compiler will create an executable program. Pass the argument to the executable program that was generated.

Comment: gcc is compiler not interpreter. You do not execute your programs in C like python scripts.

Comment: Are you compiling your executable to a .txt file?

Comment: no, parole.txt has to be an argument in argv. I guess .exe is missing in my call

Comment: @Andrea `.exe` is only needed in Windows, not in *nix. You haven't mentioned any specific target.

Comment: @Lundin Probably OP is not cross compiling, but I suppose it is a possibility. But, the output message from the compiler indicates Windows.

Comment: `parole.txt` is indeed a command line argument. But for the compiler, not for your program.

Answer (score 3):

This gcc call doesn't make sense. `-o` specifies the name of the output executable and you told it to name that executable `parole.txt`, which isn't a good idea.

The `ciao` part sounds like something you should be passing to your application, not the compiler. Compile first, execute the program next.

That is, you should do something like this (assuming Windows):

```
gcc my_code.c -o my_prog.exe
my_prog.exe ciao
```

Now if you have `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` in your program, `ciao` will be the string pointed at by `argv[1]`.

Comment: parole.txt is a txt file that i need to pass to contaparolefile.c, so i need it in argv. "ciao" is a string that i also need in argv

Comment: @Andrea You can't pass text files to c files, you can only pass them as input to the compiled executable. Or rather the file name of the text file.

Comment: so i should run: gcc contaparolefile.c -o conta.exe and then conta.exe parole.txt ciao? But i don't understand if my_prog.exe is an arbitrary name or if i need to create it

Comment: @Andrea Yes you should do it like that, then parse the command line args from inside your program. You can name the executable whatever you fancy, but it should be something ending with `.exe` in Windows.

Comment: I tried and it gave me this error: The term 'conta.exe' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, executable program or script file name.

Comment: When you run `gcc contaparolefile.c -o conta.exe` do you get any error messages? If not, does it create a file `conta.exe` in the current directory? If yes, then try `.\conta ciao`. You need to tell us more.

Comment: yes the file is created correctly. Typing .\conta ciao nothing happens